# Solr - format date

Tags: java, date, solr, jodatime, solrj

I have a problem during the filling of a data type in all my documents in solr.
I am using solr 6.2.1 and solrj 6.2.1
When I used solr 5.2.1 I had not this problem with same code.

I have some documents with a field "message_type" of type date filled like this "2016-10-25T07:15:43.921Z".. My work is take these documents, fill a new field and update all in solr..

When i read the document, pass the values of each document in a Object with an attribute messageType

> org.joda.time.DateTime

`(messageDate = (new DateTime(object, DateTimeZone.UTC));)` where object is taken from the solr document and in debug i see is the type Date and has this value "Tue Oct 25 09:15:43 CEST 2016"..
After this assignment, messageType is "2016-10-25T07:15:43.921Z" the same that I had in the original document..

When I add the document to the solr client like this:

```
solrClient.add(solrDocuments);
```

I had this error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-3" org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at http://........../solr/ion_message_collection: Invalid Date in Date Math String:'org.joda.time.DateTime:2016-10-25T07:15:43.921Z'
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.executeMethod(HttpSolrClient.java:592)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:261)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:250)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrRequest.process(SolrRequest.java:149)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.add(SolrClient.java:106)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.add(SolrClient.java:71)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.add(SolrClient.java:85)
```

the problem is...
when I build the SolrInputDocument I do this :

> document.addField(message_date.name(), message.getMessageDate());

and the result of the document's field is

> "message_date" -> "message_date=2016-10-25T09:01:38.667Z"

--> that "Z" cause the problem...

because, if if I do this :

```
document.addField(message_date.name(), (message.getMessageDate() != null ? message.getMessageDate().toString().substring(0, message.getMessageDate().toString().length() -1) : null));
```

the problem is solved...

But I don't like this solution... Some suggests to have the same time without "Z"?

Comment: Why not just use `java.util.Date`?

Comment: Sincerly I don't know (and I can't change it maybe)... The problem is that with sorl 5.2.1 works... But now we have the esigence to upgrade our version of solr